# Increase values of elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array like so...

`let myArr = [0,0,2,0,0];`

I want to create sort of a ripple effect such that the result of the array is `[0,1,2,1,0]`

Comment: what you have tried? seems to be straight forward, try with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you the result you expect:

```js
let myArr = [0, 0, 2, 0, 0];


createRippleArray = (myArr) => {
  if (myArr.length % 2 === 0) {
    console.error("createRippleArray: Array length needs to be odd number>1");
    return [];
  }

  let midIndex = ~~(myArr.length / 2);
  let mid = myArr[midIndex];
  return myArr.map((e, i) => {
    let res;
    if (i < midIndex) {
      return ~~(mid / Math.abs(midIndex - i + 1));
    } else if (i === midIndex) {
      return mid;
    } else if (i > midIndex) {
      return ~~(mid / Math.abs(midIndex - i - 1));
    }
  });
}

console.log(createRippleArray(myArr));
```

Hope this helps!